# Debugging recursion is so hard

Tags: debugging, recursion

is there anyway that i can debug infinite recursion errors fast?I get an infinite recursion error and i know that it happens because a base case is missing so its executing itself so many times that the call stack is exceeded. But my problem is with finding where exactly its missing the base case and to do so by just steping out and in using the developer tool debugger in the browser will take hours. So is there anyway that i can do it fast and jump to exactly where the base case is missing?
(pause on exeption doesnt work for the recursion)

Comment: Relatively cheap: print before your recursion step what values you call with. Or print the values of the arguments as you start the function. You can very quickly scroll through the log to find where the printed lines start to repeat. Your recursion algorithm has a problem handling those or the preceding ones.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do what you want to do. If you had an infinite `while` loop, you wouldn't expect the computer to magically tell you when the loop should have ended because the computer has no idea what you want. Similarly, if you have infinite recursion, there's no way for the computer to tell you where the recursion should have ended because the computer has no idea what you want.

There are some general tips for both programming and recursion which will simplify the task.

First, always try to simplify your code as much as possible. If your code is too complicated, try separating the code into helper functions and documenting exactly what the code should do using documentation comments or doc strings, and test each function one at a time. If you're writing a basic `factorial` function, it's almost inconceivable that you would miss the base case if you have any practice in recursion because the code is so short. But if you're writing something very complicated (ie 10+ lines), it's easy for mistakes to slip through the cracks.

Second, you should make sure that you have a proper notion of the "size of the input" and ensure that whenever you make a recursive call, you make the call on a smaller input. Remember that "size" must be measured by an unsigned integer (aka natural number) - you can't let size go negative, and you can't let size be a fraction. As long as you do these checks, your recursion will always terminate.